# How to send an email from after post request?

Tags: python, flask, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email after a post request from a template blog site made with flask. All the variables i need are appearing correctly, but the `send_mail` function appears to not work within the code block.

```
def send_mail(who_will_receive: str, subject: str, message: str):
    """Sends an email to someone.

    :param who_will_receive: str - user who will receive the mail.
    :param subject: str - Title of the email.
    :param message: str - Message on the body of the mail
    """

    my_google_email = "email@gmail.com"
    # noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
    password_google = "apppassword"

    with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587, timeout=120) as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=my_google_email, password=password_google)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=my_google_email,
            to_addrs=who_will_receive,
            msg=f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{message}".encode("utf8")
        )       # envia um email para uma conta específicada



@app.route("/contact", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def contact_page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        message = request.form['message']
        print(name)
        print(email)
        print(phone)
        print(message) # all these variables are working, but when it comes to send the email, it simply does not appear on my inbox.
        send_mail("mymail@gmail.com", f"Contact from {name}", f"Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nPhone Number: {phone}\nMessage: {message}") # The program executes fine but the email does not appear.
        return render_template("contact.html", form_submitted=True)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("contact.html")
```

I've tried changing the google app password thinking it might be the problem, but it still keeps happening.
I've also tried to add `timeout=120` keyword argument to the connection, but it seems unrelated to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing firs make sure you allowed less secure apps on your google account.
secondly you may try to use a library called [flask-mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) which is working great

```
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'mail@gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'mailpassword'
    app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'noreply@gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_MAX_EMAILS'] = 50
    mail = Mail(app)
    @app.route("/contact", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def contact_page():
        if request.method == "POST":
            name = request.form['name']
            email = request.form['email']
            phone = request.form['phone']
            message = request.form['message']
            recipient_list = []
            with mail.connect() as conn: 
                for recipient in recipient_list:
                    msg = Message(subject='subject', recipients=[recipient])
                    msg.body = f'''
{name}
{email}
{phone}
{message}
'''
                    conn.send(msg)
            return render_template("contact.html", form_submitted=True)
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("contact.html")
```

again if you want you can move this to function but I bealive in this way it is more understandable.